# Change url path of a dynamically generated <a> element

Tags: javascript

I have this `<a class="myclass" href="#">test</a>` element which appears dynamically on a page, how do I modify the href as soon as I find the element with `myclass`?

My initial approach has been to add a onclick eventlistener as shown below but doesn't seem to "overwrite" the original href url

```
$('body').on('click', '.myclass', function(){
         window.location.href = "https://abcdef.com";
      });
```

I could add a check every *1000ms* and use `getElementsByClassName` but doesn't look like a good approach

Comment: You're already using jquery, so `$('.myclass').attr("href") = "http://example.com"`

Comment: I actually found out I can't use jquery

Comment: The native method is "[setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)"

Comment: So if I get the element via getElementsByClassName and .setAttribute via javascript vanilla, it works even if the element gets created later on in the page?

Comment: Spectric's answer is your answer - use that.

Comment: @NathanBernard -- nope, I misunderstood the question, missed the bit where the element wasn't necessarily present immediately. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen for changes in the body's `childList` and change the `href` attribute of the element should it be an anchor:

```js
let observer = new MutationObserver(records => {
  for (const record of records) {
    for (const added of record.addedNodes) {
      if (added.nodeType == 1) {
        added.href = "https://stacksnippets.net"
      }
    }
  }
});


observer.observe(document.body, {
  childList: true
});

setTimeout(() => document.body.innerHTML += `<a class="myclass" href="#">dynamically added anchor</a>`, 1000)
```

Comment: Since I have to use a timeout with the method above, doesn't make sense to use instead a simpel timeout with inside a queryselector by classname and change the attribute so to avoid any possible error (like modifying another appearing href if added in the future) ?

Comment: @NathanBernard The `setTimeout` dynamically appends an element after 1 second; it is only for demonstration.

Comment: It doesn't work, but a simple setInterval doesn't work either, so must not be your code specifically obviously, it's a wordpress site so can be anything for real, I tried a simple alert("test") to check if javascript was even allowed in that place and seems to appear so I really don't know wtf is happening

Comment: @NathanBernard Doesn't work, as in, doesn't change the `href` attribute?

Comment: yes exactly, may be a ES version incompatibility? ik that wordpress is in the medieval age for what concern jquery and js versions, they've updated jquery with one of the latest patches after 20 years

Answer (score 0):

I have been using it in my projects for a while

```
function waitForElm(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        });

        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
}
```

To use it:

```js
waitForElm('.some-class').then(elm => console.log(elm.textContent));
```

or with async/await

```js
const elm = await waitForElm('.some-classs')
```